# Unable to Pull price of product

Tags: price, static-block

I think I am missing something simple and  just lack the understanding to notice it.

I have created script to pull a category and list it in a slider but I am unable to actually call the price. It just displays blank. I don't know what I have done wrong, can anyone suggest a fix? Or explain why it is not showing?

```
<?php
    $categoryid = 6;

    $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->load($categoryid);
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>

<div class="featured">  
    <div class="box-collateral box-featured block">
        <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
                <!-- Carousel -->
            <div class="jcarousel">
                <ul>
                <?php foreach($collection as $_product):?>
                    <li>
                        <div class="sliderblock">
                            <div class="product-block">
                                <div class="image">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(192,192) ?>" width="192" height="192" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?>" /></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="product-meta">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_product->getName()) ?></a>
                                </div>

                        <div class="price"><?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-featured') ?></div>

                                <div class="addtobasket">
                                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Buy') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Buy') ?></span></span></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <!-- Prev/next controls -->
                <div ="slidercontrols">
                    <div class="control-left">
                        <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev"><?php echo "<";?></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-right">
                        <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next"><?php echo ">";?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. I had to change:

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-featured') ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice(),true,false);?>
```

Comment: It says I need to wait another 20 hours or I would